# How can I create a powershell script that will delete the directory it lives inside of?

Tags: powershell

This is my current script:

```
$script_dir = $PSScriptRoot
$git_dir = (get-item $script_dir).parent.FullName
Write-Host $git_dir
Remove-Item -Path $git_dir -Recurse -Force
```

But as you can imagine, it won't delete itself or the directory it lives inside of. Is there a way to call it externally so it can clean the directory?

Comment: You do realize that `$git_dir` is actually the parent directory of the parent directory where your script is right?

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon I do yes. my scripts are in a dir called scripts and I want to move one up and remove the entire cloned dir.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change location then delete $PSScriptRoot

```
Set-Location C:\
Remove-Item -Path $PSScriptRoot -Recurse -Force
```